# Doubt in the usage of was in two sentences

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

I was making complex sentences in the class today. There I got stuck in two sentences similar to these:

> The percentage of car accidents – **which *was* recorded** at 30% – was high.
>
> The percentage of bus accidents – **which accounted** for 30% of all accidents – was high.

Why is *was recorded* used in the first sentence and why *was* is not used with accounted in the second sentence? Grammatically, both seems correct to me.

Comment: *Which was accounted* could have been used; had it been, it would have been *which was accounted for **in** 30% of all accidents.*

Answer (score 2):

The only reason seems to  be  recorded  can be used in the passive and the active voice.

Account for  is  a phrasal verb which is usually not used in the passive voice.

Here is a link

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account-for-sth